When an element near the star surface absorbs the discrete frequency of star's em radiation do this absorbed photons ought to accumulate?
We all know about emittion lines that are empty from a discrete em freqency depending on the element that absorbs that frequency band near the star which we observe when looking at these astrophysical objects..But radiation emittion is constant...what then happens to all that radiation collected by the element...does it somehow sink somewhere in the 4th dimension invisible to us?Thanks for a clear answer...

It gets absorbed along our line of sight, and then re-emitted in a random direction. Therefore the amount that reaches us is vastly diminished.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer What it mean random direction?Should at least some of as You said random photons reach our region??

Yes of course, that's why I said "vastly diminished" and not "completely erased".

At least according to current scientific consensus, nothing can "sink into the 4th dimension invisible to us". The "fourth dimension" is time. As Marius correctly pointed out, the radiation sinks into the well known three spatial dimensions.

Material that is in thermodynamic equilibrium emits just as much as it absorbs. For every atom that absorbs a photon there is another that emits a photon. The latter photon does not have to be directed towards us. To a good approximation, the outer layers of a star are in thermodynamic equilibrium.
Inside the star everything emitted is reabsorbed and the thermodynamic equilibrium is almost perfect. The "surface" (photosphere) is defined by where outwardly directed photons can escape. Those that do so come from a depth and temperature below the photosphere that depends on the opacity at that wavelength. At relatively opaque wavelengths at the centre of an absorption line, that radiation comes from higher-up, cooler layers and is less bright. Outside of those wavelengths, opacity is lower and that radiation arrives from deeper, hotter and brighter layers. Hence absorption lines.
